# ValueError / UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, geojson

So I've wanted to create a program that displays the past 30 days earthquakes on a graph and I have been using this GeoJSON data:

[https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson][1]

This is my program. I am not too sure on what to do. I was told before when I was given the UnicodeDecodeError to include encoding="utf-8".

Any help would be nice

Main.py

```py
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

#Read the structure of the file 
readable_file =  "Part 2\Data\JSON Files\Readable.json"
original_file = "Part 2\Data\JSON Files\EQ1.json"

with open(original_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)


# To write in the readable file:
with open(readable_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent= 4)

print(len(all_eq_data))

#Info Grabbing
all_eq_data = all_eq_data["features"]
mags, longitude, latitude= [],[],[]

for eq_dict in all_eq_data:
    mags.append(eq_dict["properties"]["mag"])
    longitude.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][0])
    latitude.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][1])
 

print(mags[:10])
print(longitude[:5])
print(latitude[:5])


#Plotting the earthquakes 
data = [{
    "type": "scattergeo",
    "lon": longitude,
    "lat": latitude,
    "marker": {
        "size": [5*mag for mag in mags],
        "color": mags,
        "colorscale": "Viridis",
        "reversescale": True,
        "colorbar": {"title": "Magnitude"},
    },
}]

custom_layout = Layout(title= "Global Earthquakes")

fig = {"data": data, "layout": custom_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename="global_earhtquakes.html")
```

But when I run the program I am hit with a massive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amanm\Desktop\Python\Python Crash Course\Part 2\Data\Downloading Data 2.py", line 51, in <module>
    offline.plot(fig, filename="global_earhtquakes.html")
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 573, in plot
    figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 553, in return_figure_from_figure_or_data
    figure = Figure(**figure).to_dict()
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_figure.py", line 596, in __init__
    super(Figure, self).__init__(data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 516, in __init__
    data = self._data_validator.validate_coerce(
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 2663, in validate_coerce
    trace = self.get_trace_class(trace_type)(
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_scattergeo.py", line 2138, in __init__
    self["marker"] = _v
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4796, in __setitem__
    self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5207, in _set_compound_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val, skip_invalid=self._skip_invalid)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 2450, in validate_coerce
    v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\scattergeo\_marker.py", line 1412, in __init__
    self["size"] = _v
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4804, in __setitem__
    self._set_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5148, in _set_prop
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5143, in _set_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
  File "C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 782, in validate_coerce
validators.py", line 293, in raise_invalid_elements
    raise ValueError(
ValueError:
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scattergeo.marker
        Invalid elements include: [-1.4000000000000001, -0.55, -1.5, -0.15, -5.05, -1.1, -4.1499999999999995, -3.85, -0.05, -1.0]

    The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
      - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
      - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most relevant part of the exception you posted is at the bottom:

```
ValueError:
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scattergeo.marker
        Invalid elements include: [-1.4000000000000001, -0.55, -1.5, -0.15, -5.05, -1.1, -4.1499999999999995, -3.85, -0.05, -1.0]

    The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
      - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
      - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
```

This suggests that among the (ton of) information in that data source, in key "features", subkey "properties", subkey "mag", some values are negative, while they should be 0 or higher to be acceptable.

To try to get something out of your code and get started, you could try to set a minimum value for the magnitude values at 0, and hope there's nothing else outside of expectations:

```py
#Plotting the earthquakes 
data = [{
    "type": "scattergeo",
    "lon": longitude,
    "lat": latitude,
    "marker": {
        "size": [max(5*mag, 0) for mag in mags],  # change here
        "color": mags,
        "colorscale": "Viridis",
        "reversescale": True,
        "colorbar": {"title": "Magnitude"},
    },
}]
```